# Как правильно прописать прототип "нестандартной" функции C в заголовке H?

Tags: c

```
void *mempcpy(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t n)
{
return ((char *)memcpy(dest, src, n)) + n;
}
```

Как правильно определить ее в заголовке, чтобы компилятор не гневался, как:

```
************/include/strutils.h:40:37: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'dest'
 extern void *mempcpy(void *restrict dest, const void *restrict src, size_t n);
                                     ^
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/lsblk/misc-utils/lsblk.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В gcc (g++) пишут `__restrict__`, а не `restrict`.

В других компиляторах д.б. как-то [похоже](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict)

Comment: Уже так и написал __restrict__, спасибо. Можете посмотреть еще сюда?: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/86407f2cae326030a021f1d57c61a7b74b5e0812/include/bitops.h 

Куча ошибок типа:

    https://gist.github.com/FreakMurderer/21d4ed24c0d212ee5c3a

*Закинул в гист, так как не помещатеся в комментах...

И так далее...

Comment: Глянул, по первым errors (lines 66, 46 in bitops.h).

IMHO там все нормально (я бы только LL к константам величины сдвига добавил), по крайней мере у меня gcc скомпилировал код с этими `#define bswap_64 и htobe64`).

--

Скорее, что-то не так со скобками в вызывающем коде.

Comment: Я начал двигаться начав с файла squashfs.c -> superblocks.h по всей иерархии заголовков и добрался до проблемного файла, вот он "ndk\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include\sys\endian.h".

Если есть NDK просто заинклудьте его вместо superblocks.h - и увидите эти бредовые ошибки. Ежели я сменю платформу при компиляции на 21 (моя текущая 9), то ошибок нет, но проблема в том, что нет полной вероятности, что бинарник пойдет на устройствах ниже 21... Не знаю, че и делать.... 

P.S. Вот https://gist.github.com/FreakMurderer/d8eb156ebdd7bf6d01b3 endian.h из 9-го API. Если есть желание, конечно...

Comment: Проблема именно в этих строках 
__BEGIN_DECLS
__uint64_t htobe64(__uint64_t);
__uint32_t htobe32(__uint32_t);
__uint16_t htobe16(__uint16_t);
__uint64_t betoh64(__uint64_t);
__uint32_t betoh32(__uint32_t);
__uint16_t betoh16(__uint16_t);
 
__uint64_t htole64(__uint64_t);
__uint32_t htole32(__uint32_t);
__uint16_t htole16(__uint16_t);
__uint64_t letoh64(__uint64_t);
__uint32_t letoh32(__uint32_t);
__uint16_t letoh16(__uint16_t);
__END_DECLS

Comment: @Andreyua, у меня ubuntu, а не android, так что полностью разобраться не так-то просто.

Действительно, у меня тоже

    c.c:34:0: warning: "htobe64" redefined [enabled by default]

htobe64 определен в /usr/include/endian.h.

Во-первых, можно сделать `#undef`, а во-вторых -- не понимаю, чем Вас не устраивает уже готовый endian.h (ccылку Вы прислали, я его посмотрел)? IMHO там уже есть все то же самое.